# HttpWebRequest with large requests in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to post XML to a web service. Everything works fine until the XML exceeds a certain limit (68KB is ok, 107KB fails) when I get an error:

```
Exception calling "EndGetResponse" with "1" argument(s): 
"The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."
```

I've tried GZiping the body but the server does not seem to be able to handle a compressed message and I cannot get access to the server to make any changes to the service being called. The code I am developing is to provide system testing with a way of sending a set of XMLs to the service. The XMLs being used have been captured by the application that uses this service on a day to day basis so I know that the service can handle these XML messages, I am simply unable to configure PowerShell and `HttpWebRequest` to reproduce this functionality.

```
[xml]$envelope = Get-Content $envelopePath
[System.Net.WebRequest.HttpWebRequest]$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)

$request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;"
$request.Accept = "text/xml"
$request.Method = "POST"
$stream = $request.GetRequestStream()
$envelope.Save($stream)
$stream.Close()

$run = $request.BeginGetResponse($null, $null)
$run.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne() > $null

# this line returns the error
[System.Net.WebRequest.HttpWebResponse]$response = $request.EndGetResponse($run)
```

I've also tried using `invoke-WebRequest` and `invoke-RestRequest` but these are both really slow even when using `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`

Any suggestions of what I can do in PowerShell to get `HttpWebRequest` to work with large XML?

Comment: Have you tried TransferEncoding Chunked? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

Comment: @DavidMartin the error changes from 413 to 400 when I try `Chunked`. I've gone so far as to convert the `xml` to `byte[]` using `UTF8Encoding.GetBytes` and setting the `ContentLength` accordingly.